# How do I blend pixels in photoshop-like Screen mode in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

I know glBlendFunc is the function call to specify a pixel blend mode.

I can do the **[Multiply Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes#Multiply_and_Screen)** as in Photoshop, of which the formula is

```
C = A * B
```

where A is the source pixel, B is the destination pixel and C is final result.

Using **glBlendFunc(GL_DST_COLOR, GL_ZERO)** I'll get that effect.

So now my question is how to use the **[Screen Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes#Multiply_and_Screen)**? The formula of it is:

```
C = 1 - (1 - A) * (1 - B)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Didn't check, but the way to go is as follows.

The built-in computation that OpenGL does looks like:

```
C = A*s + B*d
```

Where you can choose the s and d.

Some algebra gives us

```
C = 1 - (1 - A) * (1 - B) = 
  = 1 - (1 - B) + A*(1 - B) = 
  = A*(1 - B) + B
```

Let

```
s = 1 - B
d = 1
```

and we get the value we want. So this should work:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_COLOR, GL_ONE);
```

Comment: Algebra! I totally forget that! Thanks, great answer.